# Yii2 Fileinput allow multiple screenshot insert

Tags: yii2

I have a Fileinput field and I want to insert there screenshots one by one, using print screen, but Fileinput remove previous file. What can I do ?

```
use kartik\widgets\FileInput

echo '<label class="control-label">Add Attachments</label>';
echo FileInput::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'attachment_1[]',
    'options' => ['multiple' => true]
]);
```

Comment: if its a activemodel, try and use the way its written in the documentation. `echo $form->field($model, 'avatar[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['previewFileType' => 'image']
]);`

Comment: Thanks for help, but it is not working